# Selecting specific records in a SQL Server database from C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, windows

I am currently trying to grab some rows from a SQL Server database using C# that are of the following criteria:

- From the `RamResults` database
- in the `Results` table
- where the `Date` column is equal to the current date

I have the following so far:

```
// Open the same connection with the same connection string.
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(DatabaseControl.conString))
{
   con.Open();
   // Read specific values in the table.
   using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Result FROM RamResults WHERE Date == @Form1.date", con))
   {
      SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
      while (reader.Read())
      {
         int resultsoutput = reader.GetInt32(0);
         MessageBox.Show(resultsoutput.ToString());
      }
   }
}
```

Using `SELECT Result FROM RamResults WHERE Date == Form1.date` throws an error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token
>   line offset = 43,Token in error = = ]

Although if I take out the WHERE statement e.g.

```
SELECT Result FROM RamResults
```

it works perfectly

Comment: Did you do any basic research on SQL SELECT syntax? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173294%28SQL.90%29.aspx Note it's the same as every other SQL mainstream SQL dialect...

Comment: == != =...in SQL == is =, also use parameters, what you have there won't work  , sql server doesn't know what Form1.date is

Comment: SqlCE does not know anything about your form, so it will not understand what `@Form1.date` means. For c#, the query is just a meaningless string. C# does not automatically replace this parameter with actual data. Some answers below show how to pass the parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Description

2 things

1. Use `=` instead of `==` because this is the right equals operator in `T-SQL`.
   Your Query should be like this

   `SELECT Result FROM RamResults WHERE Date = @Date`
2. You forget to pass in the parameter.

#### Sample

```
// Open the same connection with the same connection string.
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(DatabaseControl.conString))
{
    con.Open();
    // Read specific values in the table.
    using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Result FROM RamResults WHERE Date = @Date", con))
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Form1.date);
        SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int resultsoutput = reader.GetInt32(0);
            MessageBox.Show(resultsoutput.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try parameterizing your query and replace `==` with `=` in your `WHERE` clause:

```
// ...
using (SqlCeCommand com = 
    new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Result FROM RamResults WHERE Date = @date", con))
{
    com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("date", Form1.date));
    // ...
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Result FROM RamResults WHERE Date = @date", con))
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("date",Form1.date);
        SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
```

Always use SQL parameters instead of string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Not `==`, use `=` for equation in SQL:

```
WHERE Date = @Form1.date
```

Answer (score 1):

The operator "==" is invalid syntax for SQL. Use a single equal sign "=" in the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var query = "SELECT Result FROM RamResults WHERE Date = " + Form1.date;
using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand(query, con))
```

I would suggest using parameters as in this [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.parameters%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Replace your SQL Query with the following:

```
SELECT Result 
FROM RamResults 
WHERE Date like DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0,  getdate()), 0)
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

That is quite confusing and many people commit these kind of mistakes. While C# uses == for equality Operations (Ok We do have Equal() as well), SQL uses just = for it.

Apart from this, you also forgot to pass the parameter here

Answer (score 0):

I found two things in your code which is creating a problem

1) assign values to parameter
2) == instead of = (just to make it working appropriately with SQL )

so the code should be like this :

```
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(DatabaseControl.conString))
    {
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Result FROM RamResults WHERE Date = @Date", con))
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Form1.date);
        SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int resultsoutput = reader.GetInt32(0);
            MessageBox.Show(resultsoutput.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```